# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac {\cos x} {x^2} dx.$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

The integral equals $\frac 1 2p.v.\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {\cos x} {x^2} dx.$ I tried complex analysis. But $z=0$ is a second-order pole of $\frac {e^{iz}} {z^2}$, residue theory(with indented contours) cannot be applied here.

[Integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) says it equals $- {\pi \over 2}$.

Comment: $\frac{\cos x}{x^2}$ has a non-integrable singularity at the origin, hence, principal value or not, that is a divergent integral.

Comment: Non-believers may notice that the Laplace transform brings $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx$ into $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s^2}{s^2+1}\,ds$ which is obviously divergent.

Answer (score 0):

As Jack has pointed out the integral is divergent. I think I have worked out why integral calculator gave that answer. If we interpret the integral as the Mellin transform of $\cos(x)$
$$
I = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\cos(x) \; dx = \Gamma(s)\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)
$$
your integral is obtained when $s=-1$. $\Gamma(-1)$ diverges, but the $\cos$ term goes to $0$ so thier product is indeterminate. We have 
$$
\lim_{s \to -1}\Gamma(s)\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) = -\frac{\pi}{2}
$$